# How do I remove trailing nonalphabetical characters from every line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to remove last characters except alphabets:

```
support.help1.com,,
support.help1.com.
support.help1.com9
support.help1.com*
support.help1.com@@
support.help1.com##
support.help1.com%%
support.help1.com^
support.help1.com
support.help1.com,
support.help1.com-
```

I want my output like this:

```
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
```

Answer (score 5):

sed may help too :

`command | sed 's/[^a-Z]*$//g'`

```
# create the example output
$ echo "support.help1.com,,
support.help1.com.
support.help1.com9
support.help1.com*
support.help1.com@@
support.help1.com##
support.help1.com%%
support.help1.com^
support.help1.com
support.help1.com,
support.help1.com-" > trailexample.txt

# now edit this stream
# something like $ command_output | sed

$ cat trailexample.txt | sed 's/[^a-Z]*$//g'
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com
support.help1.com

# explanation
# sed (replace) 's/this/by-this/g' :: sed 's/[^a-Z]*$//g'
# s : substitution command, we want to substitute strings
# The 'this' [^a-Z]*$ : regexp pattern
#   ^ mean not
#   a-Z means all aLphBetiCaL chars
#   []* any number of what is in brackets
#   $ means end of line
# So the 'this' is 'any number of consecutive non-alphabetical chars before end of line'
# And the 'by-this' is empty, nothing, nada, void :: //
# g : global substitution command, means do the replacement for all occurrences
```

Comment: Didn't know that you can do `[a-Z]`, I always used `[a-zA-Z]`. Mindblowing! +1 ;-)

Comment: Btw, the `g` is not needed here as there will be only a single end of line `$` for each line ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the solution... It's working fine.

Comment: no need to pipe.

Comment: @bac0n : yes not needed in that case. As the op needs to edit an output, i do pipe

Comment: @damadam : `[Az]` takes all ascii chars from A to z including six non alphabetical ones. And `[aZ]` is a condensed writing for `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @cmak.fr whether `a-Z` is the same as `a-zA-Z` is locale-dependent IIRC

Answer (score 1):

You can use a perl one-liner for this:

```
perl -pne 's/[^a-zA-Z]*$/\n/g' input.txt
```

This reads the content of `input.txt` linewise and replaces all non-alphabetical characters (`[^a-zA-Z]*$`) at the end of a line with a newline (`\n`)

Comment: won't it be more effective if you just remove the `\n`? if it is something like `support.help1.com&"_-_(&)#`, it would let something really dirty

Comment: the `\n`is important here - otherwise every result would be printed in one line. But thanks, for your comment. I just realized that `\W` includes an underscore. So I fixed this to a more precise regex

Answer (score 1):

If you can use regex, just load each command and use that regex below (got it from [here](https://www.regextester.com/93652)):

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

This regex accept URL with `http` / `https`. Just use it to confirm if your URL is valid, ifnot, just load the string by removing last character. You can use this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262725/9670273) for that:

```
string="string.help1.com&&"
foo=string

while [ !regex(foo) ]; do
foo=${foo%?}
done
print foo
```

NB: `regex(foo)` is just the function that got the string, return `True` if the regex is well, `False` in others cases

*NB2: my syntax is probably not correct, but it's just to give you a tip*

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic regex search and replace https://regex101.com/r/gRiUTc/2

Via shell you could use

```
<input sed -r 's/(\W+|[0-9]+)$//g'
```