# viewing of files contents using command line in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

How can I display all files in current directory where the first character is numeric and last character is non alphanumeric. I already try with :

```
ls grep -E '^{[-0-9]
```

but this command line did not give me results as expected.

Comment: The line looks like it has errors; there is no pipe between the `ls` and `grep`, no close "'" bracket.. etc so I'd suggest ensuring you're asking us exactly what you tried, as it doesn't look like it'll work to me either.

Comment: Can you provide some filename example? It would be easier to understand which results you're expecting

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `grep` at all - you can us the bash shell's built-in pattern matching (globbing) feature. For example (assuming "numeric" in this context means a decimal digit):

```
ls [0-9]*[^0-9A-Za-z]
```

or

```
ls [[:digit:]]*[^[:alnum:]]
```

See for example

- [Bash Reference Manual: Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

Note that if you want to view the files' *contents* as per your title, you will need something like `cat` (or perhaps `head`) in place of `ls`.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that we could use regex directly with `ls` command, and you can simplify `A-Za-z` with `a-Z` based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186712/829702)

Comment: @damadam it's actually not regex (note the `*` wildcard where regex would have `.*` for example). I'm cautious about simplifying because the expansions are locale-dependent, as explained in the manual that I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mtodorov@efk:~$ ls | grep -E '^[0-9].*[^0-9A-Za-z]$'
0abc%
1abc%
mtodorov@efk:~$
```

Explanation: **`^`** marks the beginning and **`$`** marks the end of a regular expression, **`.*`** is a wildcard like **`*`** in shell, **`^`** within brackets negates the selection and the single quotes must be closed.

Comment: based on the regex of this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186712/829702), you can simplify `A-Za-z` with `a-Z`, so you would have `0-9a-Z`

Comment: If you looked at the ASCII table, there are characters between the capital Z and small a, so you cannot simplify A-Za-z with a-Z. Plus a-Z selects nothing, you would use A-z.

Comment: `a-Z` is a condensed writing for `a-zA-Z`, where `A-z` would take character between `Z` and `a` (6 non alphabetical character); you must try this expression, you would be surprised

Comment: It may work with GNU grep, but it is largely undocumented to work everywhere, and hereby not recommended for thenovice users. Here, for example, it isn't documented: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#classes

Answer (score 0):

Using regex matching with find:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended \
   -regex '.*/[[:digit:]].*[^[:alnum:]]$' -printf %f\\n
```

find options:

- `-maxdepth n` Descend at most n levels.
- `-type f` Limit the type to regular files.
- `-regextype type` [RE](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html) syntax used by -regex.
- `-regex pattern` RE pattern used to match the whole path.
- `-printf format` will print formatted output.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `[]` Matches a single character contained within the brackets
- `[^]` Matches a single character that is not contained within the brackets.
- `[:digit:]` POSIX standard defined class for digits.
- `[:alnum:]` POSIX standard defined class for alnum.
- `$` Matches end of line anchor.